# Check if username or email is taken?

Tags: php

I understand that this may be a duplicate post, although I am unsure how to use the posts answers in my context. I am trying to post the registered fields to the database, but if they are taken (only username and email), return to the form where the user can then edit the wrong information. Could anyone help?

I am aware that I am using deprecated tags, this is for a college project

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['interest'])){

 $firstname = ($_POST['firstname']);
 $surname = ($_POST['surname']);
 $username = ($_POST['username']);
 $password1 = ($_POST['password']);
 $email = ($_POST['email']);
 $interest = ($_POST['interest']);

 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (firstname,surname,username,password,email,interestarea,user_type) VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$username','$password1','$email','$interest','normal')");

 }
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
?>
    <script>window.location='redirect.html';</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I did have something like this, but this does not work

```
 $query2="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'";
 $result2=mysql_query($query2);
 $num=mysql_numrows($result2);


 if ($num!=0)
 {
 echo "That username has already been taken, please try again<br>
 <a href='register.php'>Register</a>";
 exit();
 }
```

Comment: where do you set `$sum`?

Comment: Edit, forgot to add some code.

Comment: It is `mysql_num_rows`. But you should start using `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: you checking `$result` but your result is in `$result2`

Comment: How would I get it so it returns to the form with the data still there?

Comment: Holy Rusted SQL injection attack opportunity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is `mysql_num_rows` instead of `mysql_numrows`:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result2);
```

[mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows)

As the page also tells you, from PHP 5.5.0, this method can not be used anymore. So suggest start using [mysqli_*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) or PDO